# Node.js Discord bot - send DM to tagged user with message text

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I have this code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "cink")){
        let memberToSend = message.mentions.members.first();


        if(message.guild.members.find('id', memberToSend.id)){
            memberToSend.send('Arabské rádio čeká na připojení');
            memberToSend.send('Arabské rádio čeká na připojení');
            memberToSend.send('Arabské rádio čeká na připojení');
            memberToSend.send('Arabské rádio čeká na připojení');
            memberToSend.send('Arabské rádio čeká na připojení');
            return;
        }else{
            message.reply("Error.");
            return;
        }
```

I do not know how to change to allow me send text string that will be send to user's DMs.
So command should look like:

!cink AnyText @AnyUser#1234

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: That looks like the node version. You need to go to your `package.json` file and under `dependencies`, you need to check what the `discord.js` version is

Comment: Yes sorry :D
"discord.js": "^11.6.4"